# I can't execute stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pdo

I can't execute stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 using PDO and freetds (tds version=4.2, FreeBSD 10.0, php 5.6.2 ):

```
$host = 'SRV1';
$db = 'FLOT_RRR';
$user = 'coolman';
$pass = '******';
$charset = 'windows-1251';
$dsn = "dblib:version=4.2;host=$host;dbname=$db;$charset";
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);   
} catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage()) ;
}

$st = $pdo->prepare('EXEC dbo.getNumberSmallShips');
$res = $st->execute();
```

`var_dump($res)` returns bool(false)

My stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getNumberSmallShips] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT COUNT (*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             FLO_RN, FLO_FKL 
         FROM 
             flotmintrans 
         WHERE 
             FLO_FKL LIKE '%мс%' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '%категория%' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '%категория 3%' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '%категория 4%' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '%категория 5%' OR      
             FLO_FKL LIKE '1' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '2' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '3' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '5' OR
             FLO_FKL LIKE '4' AND 
             FLO_DSU IS NULL) AS subquery
END
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

User coolman who connects to DB must have rights to execute stored procedure getNumberSmallShips. That's it.